# In-App Purchase - Developer Purchasing Products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I suppose this question is answered somewhere, but I'm unsure how to ask the question, so I haven't found an answer.

Suppose a developer has an app with in-app purchase content that he wishes to use himself on his own device. Does the App Store recognize by his Apple ID that he is the developer and not process the charge?

This issue could be circumvented by using a test user account, but what happens if the developer uses a developer Apple ID in production on his own app?

Answer (score 3):

`Does the App Store recognize by his Apple ID that he is the developer and not process the charge?`

- No, if you download an app from the App Store and purchase an In-App Purchase with a "normal", non test account, you will be charged as any other user would.

*I read this part of the question wrongly*
`What happens if the developer uses a developer Apple ID in production on his own app?`

<strike>- You can't. The purchase fails if you attempt to use a test account on a production app.</strike>
 - It's treated like any other normal ID.

In your comments you mention: `my Apple ID is somehow recognized so no [iAds] are provided.`

- I can only speculate on this one, but I've noticed this too. I think it's the *device* that's recognised as a test device as I often see the Test iAds, not only in my own released apps, but those from other developers.

Comment: Keep in mind that you still get your 70% cut of your purchase so buying your own apps or your own apps' IAPs only costs you 30% of what it costs everyone else.

Comment: "What happens if the developer uses a developer Apple ID in production on his own app?" Of course you can. Note I did NOT say a test account ID. I don't know about other developers, but the Apple ID I use for my developer account is the same ID I use for purchasing in other apps. I have separate test account IDs for testing my own apps. In other words, I'm talking about the same Apple ID the developer uses to upload the app (not test account users).

Comment: By the way. part of why I asked the question in the first place is that I recently added iAd to my app. I expected to see ads on the version with iAd, but I have not so far. I can think of two reasons: either ads simply haven't been served yet or they're not served because my Apple ID is somehow recognized so none are provided. Given the previous answer, I suppose the reason I have not seen any ads is just luck of the draw....

Comment: Putting my cynical hat on, Apple has a financial reason not to serve ads to our own apps as well as a financial incentive to allow us to purchase from our own apps. Perhaps that's why I'm not seeing ads.

Comment: Ads are showing now. I guess there was just a delay while the app worked through the iAd system.